# Changing Attribute Name in Active Directory with Powershell

Tags: powershell

I'm trying to change the name parameter of a user in Active Directory. I have tried the below code but it's not working. The error is always "the name parameter is not known":

```
Import-Module ActiveDirectory
    
$oldName = "OldUserName"
$newName = "NewUserName"
    
$user = Get-ADUser -Identity $oldName
    
Set-ADUser -Identity $user -Name $newName
```

[image]

Answer (score 2):

To change the `name` attribute of an AD object, use `Rename-ADObject`:

```
Import-Module ActiveDirectory

$oldName = "OldUserName"
$newName = "NewUserName"

$user = Get-ADUser -Identity $oldName

$user |Rename-ADObject -NewName $newName
```